# DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. in robot framework connect Oracle Database

Tags: robotframework

I installed Visual C++ Compiler, DatabaseLibrary and cx_Oracle Library to work with Oracle Database

```
1.  Downloaded and Install VCForPython27.msi 
2.  Set Environment Variables ORACLE_HOME, TNS_ADMIN if not setup already. (eg:- ORACLE_HOME=C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1; TNS_ADMIN=%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin)
```

Installed Database Library using following command

```
> pip install robotframework-databaselibrary
```

Installed cx_Oracle using following command

```
> pip install cx_Oracle
```

After that try to connect to Oracle database as below:

```
Connect to the Database    ${oracleDbHost}    ${oracleDbPort}    ${oracleDatabaseName}    ${oracleUserName}    ${oraclePassword}
```

I am getting the error

```
DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

Same setup and code worked for other colleague, but not for me.

what went wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did setup for `ORACLE_HOME` and `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable, but didn't add the `ORACLE_HOME` to `path` environment variable.
Adding `%ORACLE_HOME%/bin` to the path variable solved the issue.